# TI DM3730 (Design reference: beagleboard) computes wrong floating point operation results

Tags: c++, opencv, floating-point, segmentation-fault, beagleboard

## The Situation

We have a board with a TI DM3730 processor (also known from the Beagleboard) with a Cortex A8 core (r3p2) in use with the following parameters:

- Beagleboard Reference Design: Beagleboard-xM Rev-C
- Kernel version: 3.2.8
- Open CV library: 2.4.6
- U-Boot: uboot-2013.04
- Toolchain: Sourcery CodeBench ARM 2011.03
- Buildroot: 2012.02
- The setup is derived from [this blog](http://blog.galemin.com/2012/03/buildroot-2012-02-for-beagleboard-xm-with-li-5m03-mt9p031-camera-support/)

Now we have written a program (written in C++ and compiled with GCC Version 4.5.2.) which uses the OpenCV library (to calculate some scores using support vector machines) and which behaves in some strange way:

1. The program runs on the board in its own process using defined test data: It produces repeatedly correct results.
2. The program runs in two or more processes (with the same defined test data): The results start to become wrong for each process, processes die with segfaults. The last remaining process runs correctly again.
3. The program runs in its own process (with the same defined test data again). Additionally, another process changes some exposure settings of an attached camera: The program starts to produce wrong results.

So we assume this is a very low level floating point problem.

### What we tried

- The complete system (all libraries, kernel, boot loader, etc.) have been compiled with compiler flags as suggested on the pandorawiki.org regarding Floating_Point_Optimization

  -O3 -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize -mfloat-abi=softfp 
  -ffast-math -fsingle-precision-constant
- We tried to enable L1NEON in Cortex-A8 aux ctrl register according to the [Beagle board FAQ](http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardFAQ) and tried the other options mentioned there as well, but unfortunately to no avail.

All three different behaviors are reproducible, but not in the form of a minimal working example.

The same program source and the first and second scenario run correctly on Windows (using Visual Studio) and on a desktop running Linux (GCC), so it's probably not something our code does.

So the questions are now:

- Are there any other known bugs with this setup and floating point operations which we are not aware of?
- Are there any known compiler options which should be set or omitted which can lead to the observed results?

If a MWE would be helpful, we will look into providing one.

Any clues are welcome.

Comment: I would try disabling `-ftree-vectorize` and `-ffast-math` initially, as both of these can result in code generation bugs. I would also try stress testing under Linux, e.g. run under valgrind, in case you have any latent memory-related bugs.

Comment: The problem sounds as if FP (Neon) state is not properly saved & restored on context switches.

Comment: @PaulR We tried to disable the two switches but then the compilation of OpenCV failed. More info when we'll have resolved that problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we now use an up-to-date buildroot (2014.08) with the included toolchain (arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgueabi-), Linux-kernel 3.9.11, boost 1.55, Qt 4.8.6, and still OpenCV 2.4.6.

When compiling, we optimize for size (–Os) and for target-optimization we only use –pipe.

The following compiler-flags are currently not used anymore:
-mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize -mfloat-abi=softfp -ffast-math -fsingle-precision-constant

Unfortunately, we still don't know the exact reason for the original problem, but we are quite happy that the problem went away with this setup.

So maybe this answer helps some poor soul in the future... ;)